# Cordova-plugin-file-transfer fails with Code 1 EEXISTS (file exists)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, file-transfer

Using cordova-plugin-file-transfer plugin version 2.0.0-7

On Android, downloading files - everything was working and then I changed a bunch of variable and function calls to clean up the code and now its not working. Obviously I changed something but at the moment can't figure out what. A print out of the error code gives me this:

```
body: null
code: 1
exception: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/MyApp/BYG/REIA_Check_List.doc: open failed: EEXIST (File exists)"
http_status: 200
source: "https://portal.mydomain.com/files/C1002/docs/reia-doc_8125235.doc?cb=1693485905486"
target: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/MyApp/BYG/REIA_Check_List.doc"
```

Its the correct source that I can download with the same direct url in a browser; you can also see the `http_status:200` verifying the source. The target is the correct location and file name...and this is the same place it was writing to prior to code changes and breaking. The error implies the file already exists but checking in the folder it does not exist, the path `MyApp/BYG/` does exist

What does this error mean: `Code 1, open failed: EEXIST (File exists)` ??

From reading other issues, Code 1 just seems to be a general error code and not specific to the actual problem. I also saw code 1 with a permission denied messages, so Code 1 just seems to mean a general failure.